# Probability of dice rolled $5$ times

Tags: probability

> In a random experiment, a fair dice is rolled until two fours are obtained in succession. Then probability that the experiment will end in the fifth throw of the dice is equal to

what i try

$A$ be the event $4$ appear and $\bar{A}$ be the event $4$ does not appear

So $\displaystyle P(A)=\frac{1}{5}.P(\bar{A})=\frac{5}{6}$

$\bullet\; $ If $4$ appear in last throw, Then

$P(\bar{A}\cap\bar{A}\cap \bar{A}\cap A\cap A)$

$\bullet\; $ If $4$ did not  appear in last throw, Then

How do i solve it Help me please

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

It is sufficient and necessary for this to occur that:

- It must not start with $44$.
- The third should not result in a $4$.
- The fourth and fifth should be $4$.

These $3$ events are evidently **independent**, so find the corresponding probabilities and take the product.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be an event when 4 doesn’t appear and $A$ be an event when 4 appears, then valid cases to end on 5th throw will be
$$ BABAA \ ABBAA \ and \ BBBAA$$
Thus Probability of ending on 5th throw will be
$$\frac{5*1*5*1*1}{6^5} + \frac{1*5*5*1*1}{6^5} + \frac{5*5*5*1*1}{6^5}$$
$$\frac{175}{6^5}$$